# Checkbox form sends zeros to mysql, whether boxes are checked or not

Tags: mysql, html, codeigniter

I've setup a checkbox form (each question has only one checkbox). The form is submitting, but it only sends zeros to mysql--whether the box has been checked or not. How can I get the correct values (1 or 0) sent to mysql?

Built in codeigniter/mysql.

**FORM**

```
<?php echo form_open('addFoo'); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo1" value="" /> //I tried this w/values incl; still zeros
<input type="checkbox" name="foo2" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo3" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo4" value="" />
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save Changes'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function addFoo()
{
    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');            
                $foo1 = $this->input->post('foo1');
                $foo2 = $this->input->post('foo2');
                $foo3  = $this->input->post('foo3');
                $foo4  = $this->input->post ('foo4');

    $this->load->model('foo_model');
    $this->foo_model->addFoo($id, $foo1, $foo2, $foo3, $foo4);
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function addFoo($id, $foo1, $foo2, $foo3, $foo4) {
        $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'foo1' => $foo1,
            'foo2' => $foo2,
            'foo3' => $foo3,
            'foo4' => $foo4
        );

        $this->db->insert('foo_table', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be values in there?

Comment: @chowwy -- Where is `$id = $this->input->post('id');` in your form and can't you set `id` to `auto_increment` in your database table?

Comment: @SpaceBeers I also tried it with values; still didn't work.

Comment: Agree with @Diodeus below. Stick a hard coded value in and see if that inserts into the database properly. It'll give you a clue as to where things are going wrong at least.

Comment: @stealthyninja - the ID isn't relevant to this question; I'm using the session ID but didn't want to add that extra info into the code, so I jus used a standard ID post. My focus is on the checkbox. The ID is working fine.

Comment: @SpaceBeers I did hard code the value; see my response below (still zeros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="checkbox" name="foo2" value="" />` <-- needs a value. Your DB inserts a zero if it's empty.

I think the issue is likely on your DB end, not the form-end.

Comment: I also populated the value field (I mentioned that in my post) and still got zero.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but what would the designated value be? I want it to insert either 0 or 1, depending on whether the box is checked or not. But for some reason, it's not distinguishing between the two.

Comment: In the controller, I put $foo1 = $this->input->post('foo1', '1'); and the form submitted with a value of zero.

Comment: I think what he means is try something like $foo1 = 1 and see where that gets you.

Comment: It's working now. I checked the database and removed the default which I had set up and fiddled around with the form code. Appreciate the help.